# What format does UWP DataWriter.WriteDateTime use?

Tags: serialization, uwp

I am trying to understand how does UWP's `Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter.WriteDateTime` method convert `DateTimeOffset` values to a byte array. I expected it to work similarly to `TimeSpan`, where the `Ticks` are converted to a byte array. Surprisingly, that is not the case.

For example, for `DateTimeOffset.MinValue` the byte sequence is:

> 248, 254, 49, 232, 221, 137, 0, 0

And for `DateTimeOffset.MaxValue` it is:

> 36, 200, 90, 94, 209, 192, 63, 255

I have tried comparing with output from `DateTime.ToBytes()` which gives much more reasonable results (e.g. `MinValue` yields all zeroes).

Can someone suggest or decode which logic is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Windows.Foundation.DateTime` is actually an `int64` under the covers, representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals prior to or after midnight on January 1, 1601. It's similar to a Windows `FILETIME` structure.

The .NET projection converts it to / from the `DateTimeOffset` structure for you, including any data transforms to the `DateTimeOffset` representation.

More info is [on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.DateTime?view=WINRT-18362)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and sorry for marking it this late :-) .

Comment: The only difference in case of UWP is that it also allows dates before 1601 - by utilizing negative values.